# in one class, applying decorator on a class method using another class method

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, instance-methods

I have a class `Alpha` that has method `__A` and method `__B`. they both called within the class `__init__` scope or other `Alpha` method, thus the use of double_under `__`, and they both functions on `Alpha` attributes.

how can I make another *wrapper* method `__C` to work as a decorator to extend `__A` functionality and apply `__B` before and after `__A` execution.

**the code:**

```
class Alpha:
    def __init__(self, a, b) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.run_me()
        # partial(self.__C, self=self)

    #@staticmethod
    def __C(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # self: Alpha
            self.__B()
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            self.__B()
        return wrapper

    def __B(self):
        self.b +=5
        print('Method B ran')

    @__C
    def __A(self):
        self.a += 1
        print('Method A ran')

    def run_me(self):
        self.__A()

alpha = Alpha(1,5)
```

the comments are some ideas that I've tried, but I think I doing something wrong.

**how can it be applied? what is wrong with my implementation?**

*note*: I know I can manually rewrite `__A`, but in this example `__A` stands for a lot of methods that needs to be extended with `__B` functionality. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `__C` work as a decorator for a method, it should be defined as a static method with the wrapper function inside taking `self` as a positional argument so that it can call `__B` as a bound method of the `self` instance:

```
@staticmethod
def __C(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__B()
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__B()
    return wrapper
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZJBbsIwEEWlLrPsCWaHTQMSC6QKiapJ1_QK1iQ4JWowlu0UcZZu2LSH6mk6dhJqEKje2Poevz_jmc9vfXCbnToev1pXTR5_7u7LBq2FrNEbXCRAay0rEKJWtROCWdlUKWAKBYfJE7zulOyi_PKXU4Ql4LlUkFScS6ZVYisZT4L8bB26utxKymUdmb6wqlUl_3Pw8t6g1tL0qYzRvFnaxu97f4piT15C5GQUy5564_1_z410rVFDEkmUbB6IfHFZ-8NyfpK0qZVjo1UoFHIwqEbDH1C5ES27SkOiwewGLotxntJ_8jWQN6BI9G2m7oR2s1k650nH_EBjWbjlvBuNfkKGSfkF)

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you call __C method? Why wouldn't you just declare __C like this?

```
    def __C(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__B()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__B()
```

The following code work fine at my side:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print(f"args {args}, kwargs {kwargs}")
class Alpha:
    def __init__(self, a, b) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.run_me()
    def __C(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__A()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__B()    
    def __B(self):
        self.b +=5
        print('Method B ran')
    def __A(self):
        self.a += 1
        print('Method A ran')
    def run_me(self):
        self.__C(func, "a", "b", c=5)
        
alpha = Alpha(1,5)
```